# How to attach an HTML element or a DocumentFragment to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, kotlin

I’ve got an HTML fragment like `<p>Hello, World!</p>` and want to attach it to the [container HTML page](https://github.com/loxal/kotlin-javascript-hello-world/blob/100d375078de495b68b56e8f403929b1fcedc3ec/out/production/kotlin-javascript-hello-world/index.html) that includes

```
<script src="lib/kotlin.js"></script>
<script src="my-app.js"></script>
```

There are two package that came to my mind:

- kotlin.js.dom.html.window.document.*
- kotlin.browser.document.*

Which should I use and how do I access the document’s root? I’ve already tried `document.getElementById("container")` whereby container is the id of a DIV. But this returns `null`. I also tried `document.appendChild(node)`...

Also which of the above packages should I prefer?

Comment: document.getElementById("container").appendChild(fragment) works if the element is present when called

Comment: @dandavis right, I just figured it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured out that the JS output of the compiled app needs to be below the element that is referenced inside the app.

I’ve created a [demo case that illustrates this](https://github.com/loxal/kotlin-javascript-hello-world/tree/Show-how-HTML5-DOM-access-works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="lib/kotlin.js"></script>

<p>Look inside the JavaScript Console of your browser…</p>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    console.log("Native JavaScript");
</script>
<!-- This script tag was misplaced. It needs to be placed after all elements you want to access in your DOM -->
<script src="kotlin-javascript-hello-world.js"></script>
```

Comment: The dom element must have been created by the browser before it is accessed.  Your moving of script placement accomplishes this, but you could also have it be above assuming you had the code in an event such as `window.onLoad` or `($document).ready()`.  It is about order of execution which assuming your code doesn't do anything to change the order (such as hooking an event to fire later), then it is executed as the script is read and processed.